# Subtracting a value from each element in a 2d array within a dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I am trying to subtract a value (`dark_val`) from all values within a 2D array that is within a dictionary. Currently I am looping through each key and extracting the values to a list and then using list comprehension:

```
def dark_subtract(dic, dark_val):

    band_values = []

    # loop through the keys and variables to lists
    for key, value in dic.items():
        band_values.append(value)

    band_values[:] = [x - dark_val for x in band_values]

    return band_values
```

Ideally, however, I would like to iterate within the dictionary so that I returning a dictionary rather than a list (i.e. `band_values`).

I have tried the following and it doesn't bring up any errors but doesn't change the values either:

```
def dark_subtract(dic, dark_val):
    """
    Must be a dictionary input and a variable containing dark value
    """
    for entry in dic:
        if type(dic[entry]) is dict:
            dic[entry] = dark_subtract(dic[entry])
        else:
            dic[entry] - 100

    return dic
    print dic
```

The way I call the function is as follows:

```
dark_dic = dark_subtract(dic, d_value)
print "This is the original values:\n", dic
print "This is the dark current corrected values:\n", dark_dic
```

When printed the dictionary `dic` looks like:

```
{'Band_1': array([[26176, 25920, 26816, ..., 53632, 53440, 52544],
       [25408, 24448, 23872, ..., 46592, 47040, 49216],
       [27264, 25024, 25792, ..., 50368, 51648, 51648],
       ..., 
       [32960, 32576, 32512, ..., 13568, 14528, 14720],
       [38784, 36416, 35648, ..., 18816, 15680, 16512],
       [33152, 32512, 32192, ..., 14464, 14720, 14784]], dtype=uint16)}
```

The dark_val is just an integer (currently set to 75)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a NumPy array. Therefore, you can subtract the integer directly:

```
 for key, value in dic.items():
      dic[key] = value - dark_val
```